# Friend explicit specialization of function template and ADL

Tags: templates, c++14, template-specialization

Why in the following the partial specialization is not selected by ADL?

```
template<class T>
void func1(T&){     // selected
    ...
}

namespace first{
    template<class R>
    struct foo{
       friend void func1<>(foo<R>&){        // expected
          cout << "foo.func1" <<endl;
       }        
    };      
} 

foo<int> f;
func1(f);
```

Comment: Do you mean `first::foo<int> f;`?

Comment: I don't think this code is valid.  I get "error: defining explicit specialization 'func1' in friend declaration".  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/728b83afb9b416a4

Comment: The code should not compile, what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template parameters are unrelated with friend declarations. You'll need to carry them disambiguated in the`friend` declaration:

```
template<class R>
struct foo{
   template<typename U>
   friend void func1<U>(foo<U>&){
      cout << "foo.func1" <<endl;   // cat();
   }        
};
```

Also for your case you should decide, if you want to put the friend definition inlined as above, or just provide a declaration:

```
template<class R>
struct foo{
   template<typename U>
   friend void ::func1<U>(foo<U>&);
};
```

The latter should match the `friend` template function in the global namespace explicitly, and specialization can be made as necessary:

```
template<>
void func1(int&){
   // ...
}

template<>
void func1(std::string&){
   // ...
}

// a.s.o.
```

Comment: I believe your first example is ill-formed, ndr.

Comment: Thank's, separating friend declaration params from the template class param make it works.

Comment: @Barry, yes it is partially, but changing the part "func1<U>" to "func1" and leaving  the other parts as it is, fix the issue of "no partial specialization error" is this is what you refer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide an specialization of `func1`. Just provide an overload:

```
namespace first {
    template <class R>
    struct foo {
        friend void func1(foo& ){
            std::cout << "foo.func1" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}

int i;
first::foo<int> f;

func(i);  // calls ::func<int>
func1(f); // calls first::func1(first::foo<int>& );
```

Otherwise, you can friend a specizliation, but you can't define a specialization in the class body:

```
template <class R>
struct foo {
    friend void func1<>(foo& ); // friends ::func1<foo<R> >
};
```

Comment: "but you can't define a specialization in the class body". @Barry if you look into the first scenario the specialization is made using foo<int>& instead of foo<R>& and the compilation fail because it can't find "cout" when linking but if instead you use "printf" the compilation succeed and friend specialization is chosen.

Comment: @xhamr 1) That's not a compile failure, that's a linker error 2) The code should fail to compile due to the explicit specialization... or at least would have ODR issues. Way simpler to overload.

Comment: @xhamr Sorry, doesn't have to fail to compile. See [\[temp.expl.spec\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#6).